# how to remove an item in the headerCt from EXT grid

Tags: extjs, grid

In EXT 4.2, i want to remove an item ("columnItem") in headerCt of grid

i found it work by remove it in the listener boxready and use the headerCt.getMenu()

but somehow when i trigger the column-header , item ("columnItem") is added back to the column-header .

can somebody help me?

```
boxready: function(){
                mainMenu.remove("columnItemSeparator");
                mainMenu.remove("columnItem"); }
```

Comment: Do you want to remove the entire column or just the header of the column?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the entire column you can use `reconfigure(columns)` passing the columns you want to have in your grid as a parameter.

**Exemple:**

```
listeners: {
                beforerender: function (cmp) {
                    let columns = cmp.getColumns();
                    columns.forEach(function (column, index) {
                        if (column.dataIndex === 'phone') {
                            //in this case removing the phone column
                            columns.splice(index, 1);
                        }
                    });
                    cmp.reconfigure(null, columns);
                }
            }
```

[Working Exemple](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2veh)